# Unity 5.4.0f3 (x64) standalone build not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've decided to make a simple game following [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) In testing mode, everything works great, but after building the scene (Standalone,Target: Windows, Architecture x86_64) the .exe doesn't want to work and no output_log.txt appeares in build data folder. The build works on the other computer tho'

I have tried to switch on and off various options in project settings>player>other settings> rendering but it didn't work. I have also switched off to default full screen mode in project settings>player>resolution and presentation but it didn't make a change. I have no idea what to do >o<

Comment: What do you mean it works on the other computer? Also could you provide some more information? For instance can you find the application in the computer's active process list?

Comment: I meant that the build works on other cumputers. And no, there is no active process after trying to launch the exe file. I've tried to run other games built with unity but the didnt work either. Clearly, there's something missing on my PC.

Comment: Have you managed to build and run other projects before? If so you might want to package your current work and import it in a new project (I recall something like that happening to me once, but sadly I don't know the underlying problem). Hope that helps.